# Model manager for start_date and end_date not working if date is set in the future

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

Im trying to write a model Manager to get all entries that is published, and start_date is in the past of `now`. The strange thing is if I set the date to a value in the past (1 minute prior), everything works, but if I set the date in the future (1 minute ahead), the object does not show, even if I wait more than 1 minute to test. If I do nothing but restart the server, the entry is shown. But I can't restart the server everytime I publish an entry.

Anyone see what could be wrong with this code? Or could this be done differently?

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()


def entries_published(queryset):
    """Return only the entries published"""
    return queryset.filter(
        models.Q(start_publication__lte=now) | \
        models.Q(start_publication=None),
        models.Q(end_publication__gt=now) | \
        models.Q(end_publication=None),
        status=PUBLISHED)


class EntryPublishedManager(models.Manager):
    """Manager to retrieve published entries"""

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return published entries"""
        return entries_published(
            super(EntryPublishedManager, self).get_queryset())



class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='entries', blank=True, null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_publication = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Date and time the entry should be visible")
    end_publication = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Date and time the entry should be removed from the site")    
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = EntryPublishedManager()
```

My view is like this:

```
class EntryListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = "entry_list"
    paginate_by = 20
    queryset = Entry.published.all().order_by('-start_publication')
```

## Edit:

If I move `now = timezone.now()` inside the def for `entries_published` the `CategoryDetail` view gets the correct published entries. Any idea why `EntryListView` does not show the correct ones?

Here is my `CategoryDetail` view

```
#View for listing one category with all connected and published entries
class CategoryDetail(ListView):

    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Entry.published.filter(categories=self.category).order_by('-start_publication', 'title')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CategoryDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in the category
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

## Edit 2.

If I change my `EntryListView` to this:

```
class EntryListView(ListView):

    model = Entry

    context_object_name = "news_list"
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entry.published.all().order_by('-start_publication')
```

Everything works. Strange, but I don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: 
I think your problem is now = timezone.now() is set when you start the application. Define 'now' inside your entries_published method.

Added:
I would suggest simplifying your method to see ensure the class method is called and skip the function definition entirely.

```
class EntryPublishedManager(models.Manager):
    """Manager to retrieve published entries"""
    def get_queryset(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return Super(EntryPublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            models.Q(start_publication__lte=now) | \
            models.Q(start_publication=None),
            models.Q(end_publication__gt=now) | \
            models.Q(end_publication=None),
            status=PUBLISHED)
```

Comment: This works for one of my views, but not the one in question. Updated question now.

Comment: Im getting the same result. `CategoryDetail` is fine, `EntryListView` is not showing correct. If I restart the server, `EntryListView` is showing correct. This makes no sense!

Comment: I am at a lost. Maybe put some logs to make sure NOW is being updated.